# Fill only Half a star with SVG

Tags: css, svg

For a rating system I'm building. Would there be any way to add a css class to this svg example such that it would show only half the star filled in?

See jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cifip/2/

In this example the current fill is a yellow color. If i add the class is-half I'd like it to show half grey and have yellow.

Is this possible in SVG?

Comment: [Clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking)

Comment: worst case, you could always just draw two half-stars, each half having one of the colors.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8783817

Answer (score 22):

create a linearGradient to fill the star. The 2 stops ensure an instant transition.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="grey"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path fill="url(#grad)" d="M20.388,10.918L32,12.118l-8.735,7.749L25.914,31.4l-9.893-6.088L6.127,31.4l2.695-11.533L0,12.118
  l11.547-1.2L16.026,0.6L20.388,10.918z"/>
  </svg>
```

then set the fill of the star to this.

Comment: Great solution. For those less familiar with SVG I would give an example of how to set the fill, like `<path fill="url(#grad)" ...`

Answer (score 16):

Depending on your target audience, `<use>` on some older browsers is not well supported. The alternative is to draw the `<path>` outside `<defs>` with a function. `stop-opacity` is optional (added there for future  readers):-

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="half_grad">
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="grey" stop-opacity="1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M20.388,10.918L32,12.118l-8.735,7.749L25.914,
             31.4l-9.893-6.088L6.127,31.4l2.695-11.533L0,
             12.118l11.547-1.2L16.026,0.6L20.388,10.918z"
        fill="url(#half_grad)" stroke-width="1" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: some browsers (eg Chrome 60.0.3112.90) hold onto the original ID and will cache the svg so when that same id is referenced, it repeats the first svg from memory. when using stars as svgs, its common to use more than 1 to display something like a rating on the web - if you are copying and pasting this snippet (multiple star svgs for example), please assign a unique id to `linearGradient id` and `path fill` for each svg

Comment: instead of width and height you could set to the  viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" to set the size of the star

Answer (score 8):

### Why not use a web font?

I know you asked about how to modify an SVG image, but have you considered using a web font instead?

It's quite easy to create a font containing full, half-full and empty star glyphs. These can be mapped to any code points you like — in the example below I've used these three characters `●`, `◐` and `○`. Alternatively you could use "★", "½" and "`&nbsp;`". *<rant>Maybe someday Unicode will actually include a half-filled star symbol, but not yet. (But if you ever need a [pile of poo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F4A9/index.htm)...)</rant>*

With a web font you can get the same results as with SVGs, but with the added benefit of having ratings that can be displayed elsewhere (like search engine snippets).

#### [▶▶ JSFiddle link ◀◀](http://jsfiddle.net/25EXa/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family:star-rating;
    src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,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) format('truetype'),url(data:application/font-woff;base64,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) format('woff');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:x-large;
}
.rating {
    font-family:star-rating;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li><span class="rating">◐○○</span> = Awful</li>
    <li><span class="rating">●○○</span> = Bad</li>
    <li><span class="rating">●◐○</span> = So-so</li>
    <li><span class="rating">●●○</span> = Good</li>
    <li><span class="rating">●●◐</span> = Great</li>
    <li><span class="rating">●●●</span> = Brilliant</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

You can make your own web fonts quite easily at places like [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/).

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but for me we decided to stick with SVG for our icons/retina so would rather stay with that for consistency. But for others this is a very good solution.

Comment: As for webfonts, sometimes we need to show 4.3 point. Webfonts unfortunately have full, empty and half star icons.

Answer (score 2):

I used all the techniques in all the answers and they were all 100% Correct, however I have some additional requirements i didn't mention. I need to have different sizes and colors and change them with css. So i found the easiest way was to make a 2 part svg icon.

Here is the result:

http://jsbin.com/vikoju/3/

If i was using web fonts i'd probably go with that solution.

Thanks All