# SVG Gradient "Pie Slice"

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, svg, gradient

Is it possible to shade in a corner of a shape using only gradients?
Below is an image of what I am trying to do, but had to use a circle and a path.
I know using a path is probably a better method, but I am curious if it can be accomplished with gradients.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Path is *not* the only method. Sometimes a 5 year old can outsmart me with basic shapes:-

```
<svg class="sheet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">

  <pattern id="my_pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#33ff33" width="200" height="200" />
  <rect x="50" y="0" fill="red" width="50" height="50" />
  </pattern>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 2; 
   fill: URL(#my_pattern)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note: if it is a half circle fill, you can use gradient in my [other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024934/fill-only-half-a-star-with-svg/25030720#25030720)

Answer (score 1):

Not with a single gradient. No.