# How to fill an svg image with specific length color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I need to implement star ratings in my app. But the designer only provided a border star image as attached. Now i need to repeat the svg and at the same time fill it according to the ratings as shown in second attached image. But I am not sure if filling the svg with specific width color is possible or not. I don't need full solution, any reference or concept answer is also welcome.
[the provided star svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gScOo.png)
and
[the implementation needeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc2Hx.png)
The provided SVG code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.177 7.72a.5.5 0 0 1-.376.273l-5.309.771a.5.5 0 0 0-.277.853l3.841 3.745a.5.5 0 0 1 .144.442l-.907 5.288a.5.5 0 0 0 .726.527l4.748-2.497a.5.5 0 0 1 .466 0l4.748 2.497a.5.5 0 0 0 .726-.527l-.907-5.288a.5.5 0 0 1 .143-.442l3.842-3.745a.5.5 0 0 0-.277-.853l-5.309-.771a.5.5 0 0 1-.376-.274l-2.375-4.81a.5.5 0 0 0-.896 0l-2.375 4.81zM12 6.52l-1.03 2.084a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.88 1.368l-2.302.334 1.665 1.624a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .72 2.212l-.394 2.292 2.059-1.082a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.326 0l2.059 1.082-.393-2.292a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .718-2.212l1.666-1.624-2.302-.334a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.882-1.368L12 6.52z" clip-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the query, Added the svg code

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024934/fill-only-half-a-star-with-svg/25025184#25025184

Comment: Im not sure if I can apply those properties in my svg, as my svg is border colored star, not filled. But thanks for the approach, im trying with it 

Comment: You may need to redraw the SVG since it's not actually filled in the middle at all if you want it to look filled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two quick hack solutions, both of which require modification of the SVG (and both of which could be modified in a more efficient way), and both of which use a [gradient fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients), the same basic idea that [Robert Longson suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714767/how-to-fill-an-svg-image-with-specific-length-color/71715314#comment126739758_71714767) above.

#### 1. duplicate the path, fill with gradient

1. Duplicate the path so you have one copy for the border and one copy for the fill.
2. Remove the `fill-rule="evenodd"` from the first `path` so the interior isn't subtracted, thus getting filled too.
3. Fill the first path (the "back" one) with a gradient that uses hard stops to achieve your partial fill. (I've used orange here just so you can see which is which.)

You could fiddle with the specifics of the gradient to get it exactly where you want it of course. This is just a proof of concept.

```css
svg {
  max-width: 200px; /* not relevant */
}

.stop1 {
  stop-color: orange;
}

.stop2 {
  stop-opacity: 0;
}

path.fill {
 fill: url(#gradient-fill);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient-fill" x1="0" x2="1" y1="1" y2="0.5">
   <stop class="stop1" offset="70%"/>
   <stop class="stop2" offset="70%"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path class="fill" d="M9.177 7.72a.5.5 0 0 1-.376.273l-5.309.771a.5.5 0 0 0-.277.853l3.841 3.745a.5.5 0 0 1 .144.442l-.907 5.288a.5.5 0 0 0 .726.527l4.748-2.497a.5.5 0 0 1 .466 0l4.748 2.497a.5.5 0 0 0 .726-.527l-.907-5.288a.5.5 0 0 1 .143-.442l3.842-3.745a.5.5 0 0 0-.277-.853l-5.309-.771a.5.5 0 0 1-.376-.274l-2.375-4.81a.5.5 0 0 0-.896 0l-2.375 4.81zM12 6.52l-1.03 2.084a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.88 1.368l-2.302.334 1.665 1.624a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .72 2.212l-.394 2.292 2.059-1.082a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.326 0l2.059 1.082-.393-2.292a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .718-2.212l1.666-1.624-2.302-.334a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.882-1.368L12 6.52z"/>

<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.177 7.72a.5.5 0 0 1-.376.273l-5.309.771a.5.5 0 0 0-.277.853l3.841 3.745a.5.5 0 0 1 .144.442l-.907 5.288a.5.5 0 0 0 .726.527l4.748-2.497a.5.5 0 0 1 .466 0l4.748 2.497a.5.5 0 0 0 .726-.527l-.907-5.288a.5.5 0 0 1 .143-.442l3.842-3.745a.5.5 0 0 0-.277-.853l-5.309-.771a.5.5 0 0 1-.376-.274l-2.375-4.81a.5.5 0 0 0-.896 0l-2.375 4.81zM12 6.52l-1.03 2.084a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.88 1.368l-2.302.334 1.665 1.624a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .72 2.212l-.394 2.292 2.059-1.082a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.326 0l2.059 1.082-.393-2.292a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 .718-2.212l1.666-1.624-2.302-.334a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-1.882-1.368L12 6.52z"/>

</svg>
```

#### 2. Same idea but with the inner and outer paths separated.

(If you're going to go this route you could just as easily create a path to define the shape of the fill.)

```css
svg {
  max-width: 200px; /* not relevant */
}

.stop1 {
  stop-color: orange;
}

.stop2 {
  stop-color: white;
}

path.inner {
 fill: url(#gradient-fill);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient-fill" x1="0" x2="1" y1="1" y2="0.5">
   <stop class="stop1" offset="70%"/>
   <stop class="stop2" offset="70%"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path class="outer" d="M9.18,8.57C9.1,8.71,8.96,8.82,8.8,8.84L3.49,9.61C3.22,9.65,3.03,9.9,3.07,10.18
    c0.02,0.11,0.07,0.21,0.15,0.29l3.84,3.74c0.12,0.11,0.17,0.28,0.14,0.44l-0.91,5.29c-0.05,0.27,0.14,0.53,0.41,0.58
    c0.11,0.02,0.22,0,0.32-0.05l4.75-2.5c0.15-0.08,0.32-0.08,0.47,0l4.75,2.5c0.24,0.13,0.55,0.04,0.68-0.21
    c0.05-0.1,0.07-0.21,0.05-0.32l-0.91-5.29c-0.03-0.16,0.03-0.33,0.14-0.44l3.84-3.74c0.2-0.19,0.2-0.51,0.01-0.71
    c-0.08-0.08-0.18-0.13-0.29-0.15L15.2,8.84c-0.16-0.02-0.3-0.13-0.38-0.27l-2.38-4.81c-0.12-0.25-0.42-0.35-0.67-0.23
    c-0.1,0.05-0.18,0.13-0.23,0.23L9.18,8.57L9.18,8.57z"/>
<path class="inner" d="M12,7.37l-1.03,2.08c-0.36,0.74-1.07,1.25-1.88,1.37l-2.3,0.33l1.66,1.62c0.59,0.57,0.86,1.4,0.72,2.21
    l-0.39,2.29l2.06-1.08c0.73-0.38,1.6-0.38,2.33,0l2.06,1.08l-0.39-2.29c-0.14-0.81,0.13-1.64,0.72-2.21l1.67-1.62l-2.3-0.33
    c-0.81-0.12-1.52-0.63-1.88-1.37L12,7.37z"/>
</svg>
```